# How can i make the button about audio in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, audio

I want to make a useful dictionary.

So, i want to make a audio button and put some audio to button.

but, it's a not say. i don't have a skill in Xcode.

i need to help to me about make a audio button and put some audio to button in Tableview.

I want to create audio buttons for each.

I don't know this website system and i upload picture in Dropbox.

Have nice day.

[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7bah0o513estc0w/Question.png.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

I would add a "AVAudioPlayer *audio" to your recipe object that you play when the button "Play Audio" is pressed.

Comment: Thank you about your comment. but, i can not make a your code. can the share to me?

Comment: I didn't write out any code, I was just informing you of one thing you could do. Just like how you created the name, prepTime, image, and ingredients attributes for the Recipe object, add in an audio attribute. When you initialize the recipes in your CustomTableViewController class with all the information add in it's respective audio file. You can then call on the audio attribute like you did the other attributes in your RecipeDetailViewController class. Any more help than this would be me basically doing this project for you. Here's a reference on AVAudio Player.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html

Comment: thank you about your comment. i followed some one Xcode tutorial. i want to make each button and i want to put the audio. i can make a button in storyboard and i can make a play button code. but, i can not make a like a this one.  self.title = self.recipe.name;
    self.prepTimeLabel.text = self.recipe.prepTime;
    self.recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.recipe.image]; can you show me the inform code?